# Alternate proofs (other than diagonalization and topological nested sets) for uncountability of the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, set-theory

I recently started studying set theory and am having quite a bit of difficulty accepting Cantor's diagonal proof for the uncountability of the reals. I also saw a topological proof via nested sets for uncountability which still does not satisfy me completely, given that just like the diagonal it relies on a never ending process. In fact, the nested sets proof sounds very much like the diagonalization proof to me.

Do all proofs of the uncountability of the reals involve diagonalization? Are there any other proofs I can look at to understand? I couldn't find any on searching stack exchange. Thanks.

Comment: There is no "never ending process." You should look at the proof again. It's valid, and if you have a more specific concern, I would be happy to address it.

Comment: How do you define real numbers?  If it relies on any kind of sequences then the definition is rooted in a never ending process.  I can only guess what the "nested sets" proof is but it sounds like it constructs a real number by a sequence of shrinking intervals, which is one way to *define* real numbers in the first place.

Comment: @ Potato: From what I understand of the diagonal process given on wikipedia and the nested intervals proof, both rely on some form of a never ending process. For example, the wikipedia proof on diagonalisation tries to construct a sequence that is not in our original list of sequences through in infinite recursive process. However, at no point does that process stop and actually *give* a sequence that is not in our original list of sequences, unless our original list is finite. Do you understand my point here, or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Just a quick question: Do you think that the set of _all_ natural numbers exist as a completed whole?  even though it is formed by starting with $0$ and a never-ending iteration of the process "add $1$"?

Comment: @ Arthur Fischer: To be honest, no I am not comfortable with that. Which is partially why I think I am uncomfortable with cantors proof and was looking for an alternate proof if anyone had one.

Comment: If infinite sets don't exist, there's not much point arguing about different sizes of infinite sets.  (This is a perfectly valid worldview, and there's a lot of interesting mathematics even without infinite sets.)

Comment: @MathNewbie Do you not like the part where the sequence is defined, or where we show it is not on the original list? It sounds to me like it's the first one. The process isn't recursive, so there are no problems with it going on forever. If you want to know the $n$th digit, I can tell you without looking at any of the other digits. The definition happens "all at once," roughly.

Comment: @MathNewbie keep in mind that an infinite list still has everything in it at some finite position. You seem to be assuming that, to define a position in the list, we have to step through it one element at a time. Not necessary. We can just as easily specify a rule for which elements are at which points in the list. The set of square numbers, for example, is infinite. But no single number is "infinitely far" down the line: if you ask for any square number, I can give you its *finite* position in the list. Nothing actually has to be "at infinite", just at arbitrarily large finite values.

Comment: @ above: I do get that for arbitrary large values of n, we can always have something defined by the diagonal that is not in all of the preceding lines upto n. BUT, I have trouble accepting that part generalized over all of the natural numbers by saying that it should hold to infinity. Why should I accept that this holds for all natural numbers to finally give a real? We know our intuition about process to infinity might not be correct, right? E.g., set of all even numbers <1000 is half the size of set of all numbers <1000, but set of all even numbers and set of all numbers has a bijection.

Comment: As I type that, I understand that I could also object on the same ground to the process of induction, and I don't know where that would leave me.

Answer (score 9):

The real numbers are a complete densely ordered set without endpoints. That is, there is no minimum, no maximum, between every two points there is a third, and every set which has an upper bound has a *least* upper bound.

> **Theorem:** Every countable dense order without endpoints is order-isomorphic to the rational numbers.

Since the rational numbers are not order complete, the real numbers are not order-isomorphic to the rationals. Therefore the real numbers cannot be countable.

Comment: This really seems in the spirit of the original question;  it does not require knowledge of any other uncountable sets (like the power set of the naturals), nor does it require any "fancy" machinery to prove. Of course, it doesn't let us "pin down" the cardinality of the reals the way some of the other solutions do.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the argument does implicitly use diagonalization to construct the isomorphism. This is because it arranges the construction as a sequence of required properties, and then does a construction in stages such that stage $i$ is exactly intended to make sure property $i$ is satisfied.

Comment: Carl, one can argue (and semi-correctly, too) that diagonalization is the only trick in logic and set theory, and we use it for everything. But this is not Cantor's diagonal argument in the sense that we write a table and switch digits from the diagonal.

Comment: @Carl, I just noticed that the previous comment didn't ping you (because there was another user who commented before you). Sorry 'bout that!

Comment: @ Thanks. This is kinda the type I was looking for. Can you please elaborate on diagonalization being the "only trick" in logic and set theory? For example, what if we reject diagonalization?

Comment: @MathNewbie: This is a serious claim, it's a joke. But many of the arguments in set theory eventually turn out to be some sort of diagonalization. You describe some infinite "matrix" and you go across in a diagonal fashion somehow. Rejecting diagonalization would be like saying "Let's not use multiplication!" it won't make the mathematics less sound. Infinities can be difficult at first, but once you stop trying to listen to your natural intuition you can develop a correct one (mathematically correct, of course).

Comment: This answer seems unnecessarily specific, why are end points mentioned? Shouldn't aEQ:0<a<1 be less numerous than bER:0<b<1

Comment: @FullDecent: Because $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ is **not** homeomorphic to the rational numbers. It has a minimum and a maximum, which are also known as "endpoints" in order theory. The rational numbers themselves do not have endpoints, as there is no "largest" rational number nor a "smallest" rational number.

Comment: I am talking about $(0,1)\cup\mathbb{Q} $, without endpoints. But again, since reals $ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor +x & x\ge1 \\  \left -\lfloor x \right \rfloor -x & x<1 \end{matrix}\right $ and rationals $ \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow (p+q-1)(p+q-2)/2+p:gcd(p,q)=1  $ can be rearranged to change the number of endpoints, it seems like the number of endpoints has no bearing on countability

Comment: @FullDecent: Yes, adding or removing endpoints does not change the cardinality of $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$. But it does change **the order type**. The argument is order theoretic, not set theoretic. Therefore the cardinality of the set matters less than its order type.

Answer (score 4):

The real numbers are a perfect set, and all perfect sets are uncountable. In particular, this gives a proof of the uncountability of real numbers that does not reference decimal expansions.

Comment: This is nice, because it can be pushed to prove more: Given any Borel subset of the reals, it is either countable, or else it contains a perfect set. And any perfect set is not just uncountable, but in fact it has the same size as the reals. This shows that the *continuum hypothesis* holds when we restrict ourselves to Borel sets of reals.

Answer (score 3):

Not all proofs of uncountability of the reals involve diagonalization. In fact, one can prove without diagonalization that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ have the same size, and then give a diagonalization-free proof that, for any $X$, its power set $\mathcal P(X)$ has size strictly larger. This was first noticed by Zermelo. The details can be found in this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46970/proofs-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals/47022#47022).

Briefly: You prove that if $f:\mathcal P(X)\to X$, then $f$ is not injective, by explicitly exhibiting a pair $A\ne B$ of subsets of $X$ with $f(A)=f(B)$. Zermelo's approach uses well-orderings. You find $A,B$ by using transfinite recursion, to define an injective sequence $\langle a_\alpha\mid \alpha<\tau\rangle$ of elements of $X$ such that for all $\beta<\tau$ we have $f(\{a_\alpha\mid \alpha<\beta\})=a_\beta$, but $f(\{a_\alpha\mid \alpha<\tau\})=a_\gamma$ for some $\gamma<\tau$.